# MVC Custom error and exception handling - standard through out the project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, exception

I am new to ASP.NET MVC , Kendo UI (razor) , Jquery. I have an application that throws 3 kinds of errors

1. Unhanded exceptions (400, 403,500 503 etc) - throw generic exceptions
2. Expected exceptions/ errors (custom exceptions) - e.g. Trying to create a contact that already exist in the system - The system needs to throw "Contact_duplicated_exception" and show this to the user as "Contact was previously created. This action could not proceed".
3. Model state errors (UI). Errors that I add to modelstate to showup on the page using  @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

What is the best standard way of handling the above throughout the application ?
I need to send these messages back to the user using Jquery Ajax [POST].

I have used the following concepts but I need to implement a standard way of dealing with the above
1. I have used ELMAH (for unhanded exceptions)
2. Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) in global.asax.cs
3. Custom HandleErrorArrtibute 
public class HandleErrorWithAjaxFilter : HandleErrorAttribute, IExceptionFilter

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For #1 and #3, you're looking good, IMHO. However, I think your weak-point is #2 and here is why:

1. If the exception is expected it should not be allowed to fall to Application_Error; because, well... it's expected, it's workflow, not an exception.
2. Therefore as a reaction to user input and part of workflow, it should be handled as part of #3.

So, in your shoes, I would go about in the specific instance of finding duplicates adding a validation attribute onto the potentially duplicate class like so:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class UniqueContactAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        bool isValid = true;
        Contact contact = value as Contact;
        if(contact != null)
        {
            // check for your duplicate in the database and set isValid to false if you find one.
        }
        return isValid;
    }
}
```

Usage for your metadata class:

```
[UniqueContact(ErrorMessage = "Contact was previously created. This action could not proceed.")]
public class Contact_Validation
{

}
```

Comment: Thank you will try your approach...There is also another reference to look at http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2010/11/handling-validation-errors-on-ajax.html

Comment: Also a nice approach, I like it; DRY and graceful.